# Algolia secured API Key with added filters at query time

Tags: algolia

Is it possible to use a Secured API Key in combination with another filter that is not defined inside the key?

For example, the secure key would define which items the user can access, but each search would be performed with an additional filter to limit the results by date (date > now).

Generating a new key (including the date) before each search is not practical, as it should be done on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can apply any additional filters as in a regular query, these ones will always be applied after those contained in the secured api key itself.

Comment: It works! 

var client = algoliasearch(applicationID, apiKey);
       
var helper = algoliasearchHelper(client, indexName, {'filters': 'Exp > ' + Date.now() });

I hadn't seen that the helper takes a third argument. Thanks, Karim!